Error Selecting data in Postgres using node
This is my get function
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const [userData,setUserData] = useState({});

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(Cookies.get('auth') !== 'AUTHENTICATED'){
            navigate('/');
        }
        $(".navbar").css('display','block');
        let getUser = async () => {
            const result = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/get/user${Cookies.get('id')}`);
            setUserData(result.data);
            console.log(result.data);
        }
        getUser();
    },[]);

This is my get Route
app.get('/get/user:id', async (req,res) => {
    var id = parseInt(req.params.id);
    console.log(id);
    const result = db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1',[id]);
    console.log(result.rows);
});

I am having trouble with executing the query as the query is returning undefined value.
This is my output
This is my Database
I am getting the id as a string from path variable but even after using parseInt() it is not working
EDIT: I have tried to modify the endpoint as '/user/:id' but it still does not work, still returns undefined.

You forgot to send a response in your "get Route"

Could you be clearer in exactly which of the console.log calls is outputting undefined.

'result.rows' is returning undefined

Apparently i forgot an 'await' before the database query so it was returning a promise, and thus logging undefined when trying to access 'rows'.

....meaning that the problem is solved now? Or is the question still open?
